# Does C make any guarantees about object files?

Tags: c, macros, compilation, c-preprocessor, object-files

I have some C code that I want to change, but I want to use `#ifdef`s so that it's possible to compile the old object files (the post-pre-processing code will not have changed).  For certain reasons (compiling for several platforms, and certification reasons), I need to keep the object files identical (apart from any timestamps).

Does the C language spec or do any C compilers make any guarantees about recompilation?  I've been doing a bit of Googling, but I haven't been able to find anything on the topic.

**For example:**

main.c

```
int main() {
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

main.h (new file)

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    char some_buffer[1000];
    #define PRINTF(S) (sprintf(some_buffer, S))
#else
    #define PRINTF(S) (printf(S))
#endif
```

main.c (updated file)

```
#include "main.h"

int main() {
    PRINTF("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

If I were to compile the updated main.c with DEBUG **not** defined, which now includes main.h, does the C language spec or any C compiler make any guarantees that the object file will be the same?

Comment: Maybe you should describe the "certain reasons" that have driven you to consider this solution (XY).

Comment: Anyway, the C standard only limits compilers to produce programs which have the same observable behavior as the spec mandates, program size is not defined as such observable behavior.

Comment: The exposed api will be the same, but the precise details could well change. I'd imagine that generally they won't, but there can't be any guarantees because (e.g.) optimisation is not part of any spec.

Comment: @BrianCain Sure.  I have updated the question, but essentially, I have multiple platforms, and some can't/don't want to support a particular feature.  This software gets certified, and so I don't want the other platforms to have to re-test/re-certify portions of code that get updated (but don't execute differently).

Comment: You can't even be sure that two compilations of *identical* source code will generate the same binary; GCC for example claims to use randomised branch-guessing heuristics as part of its optimisations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C language makes no guarantees about object files.  Not even that the toolchain will necessarily have anything like object files.  Specific compilers will probably have some rules about their own object files, but they may or may not be particularly well documented.

Anyway, if you already have a specific object file that you need, why do you care so much about being able to recreate it?  If you want to build an old version of the software, can't you just check out from revision control whenever you need to build it, without having to clutter the source with every version in the same place?

Comment: I have updated the question, but the reason is that I want the possibility of enabling/disabling the feature on a second platform, without the code changing.  It is certified in a certain process such that if the *.o file changes, it has to be re-tested.